# Closed form of divergent infinite product?

Tags: divergent-series, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Okay, we know that

$$  \frac{sin(x)}{x} = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2\cdot\pi^2}\Big) $$ .

Is there some known (trigonometric(?)) function that is equal to the following infinite product?

$$ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big(1-\frac{x}{n\cdot\pi}\Big) $$

I'd be happy as well if someone could provide me with a function that is equal to a similar divergent infinite product (a function, for example, that is equal to 'my' inifite product, only $\pi=1$, or $x=x^2$, or something in that direction).

Thanks in advance,

Max Muller

Comment: Your question is related to the Gamma function (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) at $-1$; but the product is meaningless, the Gamma function has a singularity there, and this all has been known for two centuries.

Comment: Ok, but isn't it pretty 'obvious' that the gamma function has a singularity there, as it's 'almost' equal to my divergent series, which goes into infinity for whatever x. It isn't that 'bad' that the function has a singularity there.

Comment: It's equal to zero because the sum of x/n pi is infinite. Use that 1 - y <= e^{-y} for positive y to find a proof. Also if you plug in x = pi into your product and multiply out a few terms it will be clear what's going on. This isn't really a mathoverflow kind of question IMO. 

Comment: Yeh, I'm sorry, I was afraid of that already, but I I couldn't look it up somewhere easily... Sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a **divergent** infinite product. You might as well ask for the sum of
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x}{n\pi}.$$
You can "cure" the divergence by multipliying each term by a suitable factor, so
for instance
$$f(x)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty e^{x/n\pi}\left(1-\frac{x}{n\pi}\right)$$
does converge (as the $n$-th term is like $\exp(x^2/2n^2\pi^2)$). You can
express this in terms of the gamma function which satisfies
$$\frac1{\Gamma(x)}=x e^{\gamma x}\prod_{n=1}^\infty
e^{-x/n}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right).$$
By using the identity
$$f(x)f(-x)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$$
one can deduce the identity
$$\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)=\frac\pi{\sin\pi x}.$$

Comment: I should add that this is an example of a Weierstrass product 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_product 
which can be used to construct entire functions with any
admissble set of zeros.

Comment: Ok, thanks, this is very useful, mister Chapman!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the development of the Gamma function

$$1/\Gamma(z) = z e^{\gamma z}\ \Pi_{n=1}^\infty\ (1+{z\over n})\  e^{-{z\over n}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the first dozen pages of Andrews and Askey, which you can read online - http://books.google.com/books?id=nMm13WXpLt8C&lpg=PP1&dq=andrews%20askey&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q&f=false

Already on page 3, they give the product representation of 1/Gamma, which is essentially your function, modified to make it convergent.

On page 10, they treat the reflection formula, which shows that 1/Gamma is "half of the sine function", i.e it contributes the zeros on the negative x axis.

Comment: Thanks, castal, I always like references to more useful information.